# GUI for Fossil SCM

Tags: user-interface, fossil

Are there any GUIs for fossil?

I've been getting used to the idea of source control for solo projects, and having an interface for the commands in fossil would help.

Something simple that helps browse for files, or open + close. Google has turned up nothing except the web GUI that works within the projects themselves.

Comment: I think the poster is after something that let's you do the command line actions from Windows Explorer or Finder, though they could be referring to IDE integration with eclipse or the Microsoft/Apple tool chains.

Comment: Something like
http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/
?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now there IS a Fossil GUI.

At the moment it has really basic functionality, but it is free and open source:

http://code.google.com/p/jurassic-fossil/

Comment: It's not maintained for 7 years for now.

Answer (score 9):

There is a Windows GUI for fossil at http://repository.mobile-developers.de/cgi-bin/ikoch/sharpfossil 
It is not yet complete, but usable and has some features fossil doesn't have.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 7):

I think you'll find the web interface, launched by the command "fossil ui" is the only user interface (graphical or otherwise) apart from a few command line commands.

What would a GUI have that couldn't be done via the web interface?

Comment: Integration with the file system? (thinking of Tortoise here)

Comment: Preview changes before committing?

Answer (score 7):

I discovered several new options for Fossil GUI recently:

- [Fuel](https://fuel-scm.org/fossil/index) - cross-platform GUI written on Qt;
- [QLFossil](http://www.codingrobots.org/p/qlfossil/doc/tip/www/index.wiki) - Mac OS X helper for these, who uses Fossil.
- Build-in web-interface become more usable on Windows. At the moment you can setup fossil to run on background, so you won't need type **fossil ui** in command line anytime you need to view history, or changes. By the way, web-interface now features a new eye-candy theme and side-by-side diffs.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a GUI for Fossil on Mac, sort of... I have been working on a simple GUI which, while not a Finder plugin like Tortoise{CVS,SVN,GIT,...}, works together with Finder.

The project can be found at http://chiselapp.com/user/sti/repository/fossil-gui/home

Answer (score 3):

Personally, the built-in `fossil ui` has been all the GUI I need for small projects.

After `fossil new` and `fossil open`, the only real interaction with a repository for a personal project is the occasional `fossil changed` and `fossil extra` to make sure I didn't change anything I didn't intend to change, and naturally `fossil ci` to check in those changes.

For browsing the repository `fossil ui` does everything I need. It is hard to beat the Timeline view, from which you can get to the files changed by that check in. There is also the Files view, from which you can see each file and inspect that file's timeline.

There is also a project in progress to write an [introductory book](http://www.fossil-scm.org/schimpf-book/index) for fossil. The current draft is well worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

The [ramdebugger TKL IDE](http://www.compassis.com/ramdebugger/) has support for fossil built in, although the fact is a bit hidden on the changes [changes](http://www.compassis.com/ramdebugger/Changes) page.

Answer (score 0):

There are no platform ui clients for Fossil on Windows Explorer or Mac OS X Finder.
There are no IDE extensions for eclipse, netbeans, emacs or the Microsoft/Apple tool chains that I can find, but there is one for a TCL IDE:

RamDebugger has some support for GUI commit & add & update with Fossil. It is an IDE & debugger for TCL.

http://www.compassis.com/ramdebugger

http://www.compassis.com/c/ramdebugger/index

- courtesy Ramon Ribó, fossil-users mailing list 1 July 2010

Sorry the answer is mostly 'no', but this response should change soon as fossil seems to be attracting a lot of attention.

Comment: There's now some code to do emacs integration: http://chiselapp.com/user/venks/repository/emacs-fossil/doc/tip/doc/index.wiki

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in web interface.

If you have an open repository 
    i.e.
    fossil open myProject.fossil

then run fossil with the ui command:
    fossil ui

fossil will run a webserver providing gui access to the currently opened repository and it will start your browser pointing to http://localhost:8080 (or some previously unused port).

Comment: While the built-in web UI is great, it doesn't help you with open/close or dealing with file status at all.

Answer (score 0):

[diesel](https://github.com/AnotherFoxGuy/diesel-scm)

A fork of [fuel](https://fuel-scm.org/fossil/index) which updated GUI framework to QT6 and usable github action workflow.

I made a fork https://github.com/sulisu/diesel-scm/tree/sulisu-patch-3 of it which removed builtin web browser and dependence of QT6 webcomopnent, reduced compiled file size to 30MB.

It's support for fossil version stayed around 2015. 2.9 works well with it, while 2.23 causes window to freeze sometime.